# Use only "street address" and zip fields for credit card form to meet AVS?

Tags: forms, addresses, credit-cards

I have a credit card form where the only two fields of the address we need to collect are "Street Address" and "Zip". Would the reduced friction of fewer fields (I would drop city, state, address2 inputs) outweigh the non-standard format of the form?

Background:
The need for both fields comes from the [Address Verification Service](https://www.cardfellow.com/address-verification-service-avs/) (AVS). In order get the best rate from some of our processors we have to have both Zip and Street Address, but nothing more.

[image]

Comment: Why would you ever ask for a city (or state) when you already got the zipcode and thus could look them up? Now if you merely displayed those so the user has an additional change to see it if they entered a wrong zip, that I could understand. But if not needed then do not even store that information, let alone ask for it.

Comment: Zip codes are decent indicators of city/state but they sometimes cover multiple cities. In that case we could certainly just fill in some inputs, but that would require displaying additional form fields, which I would like to hide to make this less daunting if possible. All part of the consideration.

Comment: Ah, then that differs per country. Over here (NL) a zipcode specifies a single street in a specific city. Which country are you asking for, or is it intended for world-wide usage?

Comment: Strictly US for now! Hopefully international someday soon.

Answer (score 1):

Street address could be slightly ambiguous, as what people consider their street address or even "first line of address" varies, person to person and doesn't always match with what the USPS considers their address to be.

For some this would include apartment numbers, or building name/number in an apartment complex, for others it would simply be a house number and street name.

So including a help text line with the field may be useful, with an example of the sort of thing you are after.